# The attempt to post data to consumer failed due to an unexpected error. Please try again later. Search Reset Filter

Tags: localhost, integration, oauth

Сannot activates an integration of Magento 2.4 with my application on the localhost. I want to activate Magento integration for testing OAuth-based authentication, but I get the message:

"The attempt to post data to consumer failed due to an unexpected error. Please try again later."

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think your domain is incorrect: it should not be https://localhost:3000.com?

Answer (score 0):

it seems your url should be

`http://localhost.com:3000/api/magento/callback`

or

`http://localhost:3000/api/magento/callback`

Comment: The answer is partially correct. My application needs the HTTPS protocol (the SSL certificate is not locally configured). But for test Magento, I just run my React app with the HTTP protocol. I think if configure the SSL certificate, then everything will work as expected.